# java.lang.NullPointerException when opening xml files in eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml

I just encountered a problem when opening my .xml files in Eclipse. Every time I try to do so, I get this error: "An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException"

I can open my AndroidManifest.xml, just not any of the other ones. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I think I figured out where my problem is coming from. I am using the Aviary API with my app and they provided a test app in their SDK to see how to implement Aviary correctly.

In my app and the test app, the manifest files both include the same android:authorities tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: It says this when I run the app:

Comment: 10-27 17:43:39.001: E/Trace(735): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: Did you try to refresh and clean your project?

Comment: Sorry, I read the question too fast... To me it sounds as you are having issues either in your eclipse installation or in your workspace. Try to start with a new workspace to see if it helps. It could also be a plugin you have installed.

Comment: Go to error log, read the stack trace and if you don't understand it - post it here.

Comment: just replace the project.properties file 
also change the build sdk version.
also replace those files .java or xml that you open and show null pointer exception 
because when you go your project folder outside from eclipse will show you that it's empty.

so replace these with your backup files.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Just messed with some of the properties in my androidManifest.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem, just changed the SDK version from a higher to lower and again back to some other higher api version and all of a sudden it started working.

Don't know if these would help you, but you can try.